# Git command displays changed files between two commits

Tags: git

I need to see the files changed between two commits. Currently I am using

```
git diff commit_id_1 commit_id_2
```

this command also displays contents in the files. I just need to see whats are the files changed between two commits. What will be the command for this ?

Comment: I marked this as duplicate because, by definition, if you can list the files changed in a commit, then you also know that the set of files is what changed in going from one commit to the next.

Comment: see `git help diff`,  `--name-only` or `--name-status`